# How come this alert of a unicode character is not successful?

Tags: javascript

I tried to make an alert popup with "A" with:

```
var a = \u0041;
alert(a);​
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tht2X/)

However, I get an error in Chrome Console: `Uncaught ReferenceError: A is not defined.`

What does that mean? I don't have a variable called `A` anywhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

\u0041 is the unicode for capital letter A. The interpreter translates it as is, not assuming that it is a string.

To alert the value rather than looking for a variable with that name, do `alert("\u0041")`

Following your code style, the modified code would look like this:

```
var a = "\u0041";
alert(a);
```

Comment: or better yet just put quotes around the `\u0041` in the variable declaration.

Comment: @alex haha well that felt obvious but I guess it doesn't hurt to show it